# How to handle live time on webpage?

Tags: javascript, time, reactjs

I have seen some webpages(for example facebook) where created/posted date for posts are counting. For example posted now, 5 min ago, yesterday at 14 and so on.

Im working on a reactJS webpage right now where this functionality would be really nice. I am sending models to the client but these are only used to generate the react code then its not used any more.

So the question is, what would be the best way to solve this? Should I maybe create a special react datetime component that are used? And if so, how could it look like?

Edit : sorry for not being clear. The time can be calculated on server but I need it to count down live on the client.

Comment: I have always used http://momentjs.com/ It is pretty great. Does front end and server side.

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with still. It seems like you're asking for someone to code a solution? Don't you just need to send the total time up ... subtract from current time to get elapsed, and then display it using whatever means/framework you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to periodically trigger a re-render so whichever components are generating the time since display will update.

Doing this with a setInterval at the top level isn't ideal, but is the easiest way to do it.

Another easy way is to create a component which takes a prop for the time to be compares against and forces itself to re-render every so often to update the displayed time.

Another way would be to keep a static list of callbacks from mounted time-displaying components which force the component to re-render and loop through them and call them periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at moment.js, specifically "Display Time from now"

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: Thanks, but what I looking for is some way to count the time live on the client in a easy way.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I have always used [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/). Again, it does Front End and server side. [This functionality](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) is probably what you can use:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I can calculate this at the server manually, no problem but what I seek is a live update at the client, so when it has gone 5 min it will show posted 5 min ago and so on without reloading page.